# Way to fake server-to-server FTP transfer?

Tags: ftp

Server A is production, Server B is staging. We're not using full version control, but need a simple way to drag and drop a few files from B to A.

I understand I could use FXP, but the server doesn't support it.

Is there a tool that will:

- FTP (download) some files to my local machine from Server B
- FTP (upload) those files from my local machine to Server A

I *thought* that Transmit for Mac could do this, kind of a fake version of FXP. But I am on Windows.